# response for preflight is invalid (redirect) for aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am trying to upload an image to my Amazon S3 bucket. But I keep getting this CORS error, even though I have set the CORS configuration correctly.
This is my CORS configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that this issue resolved after a few hours by itself.