# Fetch on AWS S3 bucket with CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, fetch

With the basic "allow all" configuration on my S3 bucket, I'm having a CORS issue on my fetch request using Chrome. Here is the CORS error: **Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request**.

Here is my configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your URL looks like this: `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/` but it should be localized, like this: `https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/`.

Comment: This is a newly-created bucket, I take it?  After the bucket is a few hours old, it should work as expected with either URL.

Comment: Yes it is! I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852612/response-for-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-for-aws-s3) sooner but it wasn't really wordy